# Debezium signal table issue

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, snapshot, debezium

I tried using Debezium (1.6) signal table to take snapshot for newly added tables in SQL Server connector. When I inserted a signal of event type execute-snapshot, it took a snapshot initially. When I sent the signal the second time, it stopped taking the snapshot and started inserting snapshot-window-open and close events into the signal table. It is inserting the records continuously without stopping, which results in high disk usage. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Updating the debezium version to 1.9 worked.

Comment: Hi how do you update debezium version?

Comment: You can use docker images

Comment: Yup. I updated the sql-server-debezium version int the kafka-connect docker deployment file. It works